# Object property name is getting capitalized

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have a form and I'm tying the value displayed in an input field to its corresponding property in the object but something weird is happening.

My user object looks like this:

```
{
   firstName: "",
   lastName: ""
}
```

If I tie my input field to the property with the name as it appears here, I can't type into my input field.

If I, however, capitalize property name - as in the code below - I can then type into my input field but I'm not able to update its value. I put a debugger to see what's going on and noticed that once I hit the onChange function, some property names are getting capitalized. So, user.firstName is becoming user.**F**irstName. So the code below allows me to type into the input field but can't capture the value entered because property name in the object is still firstName

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value={user.FirstName} onChange={myChangeFunction} />
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/snippet with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the issue. The exact way I created my input field was as below:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={myChangeFunction} />
```

As you can see, I was setting the name to `FirstName` even though the value was set to `user.firstName`.

When I changed it to `name="firstName"`, it started to work fine.